# Checking for duplicate substrings in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, duplicates, compare

I am trying to find a way to compare the first significant words in each cell with first significant words in the next cell, and if the first significant words matches, it removes the second entry. For example, the starting data can look like this:

- General Electric

  General Electric Inc

  General Electric Company

  Microsoft

  Microsoft Corporation

  Microsoft Servers

  Nintendo

  Nintendo Enterprises

And the result should end up looking like this:

- General Electric

  Microsoft

  Nintendo

So far, I have this code set up that traverses the column of data:

```
Sub CompanyNameConsolidate()
    Dim companyName As String
    Dim companyArray() As String
    Dim companyName2 As String
    Dim companyArray2() As String
    Dim totalArray() As String
    Dim wordCount As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim r As Range

With Sheets("Unassigned")

        Range("B1").Select

        Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

            companyName = Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row).Text
            companyName2 = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Text
            companyArray = Split(companyName, " ")
            companyArray2 = Split(companyName2, " ")

            wordCount = UBound(companyArray) - LBound(companyArray)

            For i = 0 To wordCount

               If companyArray(i) = companyArray2(i) Then                 

        [*********HELP**********]

            Next

            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Loop

    End With

End Sub
```

Basically, the code above compares the substrings in each cell with the substrings in the next cell. Unfortunately, that's as far as I have gotten.

The tricky thing is that some company names can have two words (General Electric) and others can have only one word (Microsoft).

You can assume that the list will be sorted in alphabetical order, so the shortest name (the name I want to keep) will always be on top.

I have over 16,000 entries to go through and fix, so I absolutely must have an automated way of doing it!

Comment: You can do a `mid` until first blank in a new column then remove duplicates. Then do another for second blank and third. Should capture most of it?

Comment: _The tricky thing is that some company names can have two words_ You a right, it gets tricky to correctly identify similarity between strings.  This might be useful: [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Comment: With regard to multi-word company names, consider how you would differentiate all the "Generals".  e.g. `General Electric`, `General Motors`, `General Mills`, `General Dynamics` and so forth.  I think you are going to need some kind of lookup; or a list of words to ignore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st variant using rows deletion:**

```
Sub test()
    Dim Dic As Object: Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim x&, cl As Range, DataRange As Range, k1, k2
    Dic.comparemode = vbTextCompare
    With Sheets("Unassigned")
        Set DataRange = .[B1].Resize(.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row, 2)
        x = 1
        For Each cl In DataRange
            If cl.Value <> "" Then
                Dic.Add x, cl.Value
                x = x + 1
            End If
        Next cl
        For Each k1 In Dic
            For Each k2 In Dic
            If IsNumeric(k1) And IsNumeric(k2) Then
                If Dic(k2) Like Dic(k1) + "*" And k2 > k1 Then
                    Dic.Remove (k2)
                End If
                If Not Dic.exists(Dic(k1)) Then Dic.Add Dic(k1), Nothing
            End If
        Next k2, k1
        x = Split(DataRange.Address, "$")(4)
        While x <> 0
            If Not Dic.exists(.Cells(x, "B").Value) Then .Rows(x).Delete
            x = x - 1
        Wend
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**2nd variant using `Workbook.Add`:**

```
Sub test2()
    Dim Dic As Object: Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim x&, cl As Range, DataRange As Range, k1, k2
    Dic.comparemode = vbTextCompare
    With Sheets("Unassigned")
        Set DataRange = .[B1].Resize(.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row, 2)
        x = 1
        For Each cl In DataRange
            If cl.Value <> "" Then
                Dic.Add x, cl.Value
                x = x + 1
            End If
        Next cl
        For Each k1 In Dic
            For Each k2 In Dic
                If Dic(k2) Like Dic(k1) + "*" And k2 > k1 Then
                    Dic.Remove (k2)
                End If
        Next k2, k1
    End With
    Workbooks.Add
    x = 1
    For Each k1 In Dic
        Cells(x, 2) = Dic(k1)
        x = x + 1
    Next k1
End Sub
```

**test for both variants**

***before:*** **~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~>** ***after:***
[image]  [image]

Comment: This one comes really close, but unfortunately it looks like it only compares the first word of each entry. So for example, if I have Major League Baseball and Major League Soccer (two unique identities that I need to keep), it will just see that the first word "Major" is the same and it removes Major League Soccer.

What I need is something that compares the entire first entry (i.e. Major League Baseball) with the next entry and makes sure the first entry isn't a part of the next entry. Does that make sense?

Comment: post has been updated, i think that now it does what you need

Answer (score 1):

Find a common demoninator for your company names, according to your examples this appears to just remove the last word, if its greater than 1 word.

```
Dim listOfCompanies As New Collection
Dim companyName As String
Dim companyArray As Variant
Dim item As Variant
Dim i as Integer, j As Integer

'The 2 denotes column B, where i denotes the row
'You can change this outter loop to your specific needs, this one just processes the first column B1, to when it encounters a blank row
while(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Unassigned").Cells(i, 2).Value <> "")
    companyName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Unassigned").Cells(i, 2).Value
    companyArray = Split(companyName, " ")

    companyName = ""
    'This truncates the last word off
    for j = 0 to UBound(companyArray) - 1
        companyName = companyName + companyArray(j) + " "
    next j

    'Trim off the last space character
    companyName = Trim(companyName)

    'Now Add your companyName string to a Dictionary Object
    'VBA will throw an error if a duplicate gets added, but this is okay and we can continue processing
    On Error Resume Next
    listOfCompanies.Add(companyName)
    On Error Goto 0 'This resets the handler in case an error occurs somewhere else unexpectedly

    i = i + 1
wend

'Now we can do a ForEach and spit out the entire 'unique list'
For Each item in listOfCompanies
    'Your code here
Next item
```